# Remove duplicate code blocks of overridden methods in Java

Tags: java

My project must comply by contract with all the sonarqube static analyzer rules (to my *immense* delight).

As shown in the picture I have a base class which is derived n time, and each derived class is derived a second time.
[image]
All my DoubleDerived classes override the methods `foo1()`, ..., `fooM()`  generating n duplicate code blocks of size O(M) lines of code

```
class DoubleDerivedX extends DerivedX {

    @Override
    public void foo1() {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public void fooM() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Currently my code violates the `common-java:DuplicatedBlocks` rule for this reason, as far as I can tell (I can't find official documentation about this) the analyzer consider a code block duplicated if it consists of three or more methods and if it is present in multiple file.

It is actually possible to remove the duplicated blocks of code, if yes how?

A trivial solution would be to use multiple inheritance, with a BaseDoubleDerived class derived from Base and from which the n DoubleDerived class derive, but it cannot be implemented in Java.

Edit: The Base and Derived classes are domain classes while the DoubleDerived classes are lazy loading Proxies that fetch data from repositories. The fact is that I can pretty much feel that this is a XY problem but I'm so close to the deadline that I know I don't have probably the time to implement the "right" solution.

Comment: Does calling `super.foo();` from within overriding methods fix your problem?

Comment: @Bohemian no, if you point out something that is not clear to you or ambiguous in the question I can try to improve it.
Calling `super.foo();` from within overriding methods implies the existence of n duplicate code blocks containing `super.foo();`

Comment: @Fabio This question does **not** show exactly what the problem is. And the unclear reason you are not happy with the current answers adds to the puzzle. The `DoubleDerived` classes override methods, by your design. What's the problem? We can only assume that `DoubleDerived` classes override because they need specific implementation, which again is what things are meant for. If you mean that all these overrides have to repeat code that should be shared, then I don't see why you reject the option of extracting those pieces to common super methods or use composition...? (1/2)

Comment: @Fabio Or are you saying that `DoubleDerived` in the `1` tree does not necessarily need all "reusable" code that is needed by `DoubleDerived` in the 2 tree?  And regarding multiple inheritance... You don't need it. What is the reason not to reduce the number of `Derived` classes, making them bear just what's shared/common among the `DoubleDerived` classes up their tree? Please also add the reason why "not considered a solution" are not good solutions, it may clarify the question.

Comment: thank you all for your interest and for your patience, I will re-edit the question trying to solve all the doubts and the issues you have pointed out.

Comment: Two questions. (1) Could it be solved by reorganizing your inheritance tree so that the classes that are now singly derived go in one subtree and the classes that are now doubly derived go into another? (2) Did you look at the *strategy* design pattern?

Comment: @Ole V.V. I'm familiar with the GOF patterns but I can't currently see a sulution using any pattern, it feels more like a language limitation. My classes are organized in this way to be able to use polymorphism, I don't think it is possible to rearrange the inheritance tree, please let me know if you need any additional infrmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: They may say that *I don’t believe in ‘if’ anymore* is the object-oriented battle song (well, actually they don’t, I just made this up). `if` statements still have their place.

```
public class Base {

    private boolean needsFooImplementationsForDoubleDerivedClasses;

    public void foo() {
        if (needsFooImplementationsForDoubleDerivedClasses) {
            // DoubleDerivedX foo() implementation here
        } else {
            // Base foo() implementation here
        }
    }

}
```

Now control the value of `needsFooImplementationsForDoubleDerivedClasses` through constructor arguments. Like this:

```
class DoubleDerivedX extends DerivedX {

    public DoubleDerivedX() {
        super(true);
    }

}
```

**Original answer**

One option is: put the common implementation for double derived classes in a separate method in the base class. Base and single derived classes will not need it and just ignore it.

```
public class Base {
    public void foo() {
        // Base foo() implementation here
    }
    protected void fooImplementationForDoubleDerivedClasses() {
        // DoubleDerivedX foo() implementation here
    }
}
```

So your double derived classes only need to do

```
class DoubleDerivedX extends DerivedX {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        fooImplementationForDoubleDerivedClasses();
    }

}
```

Depending on your situation putting the common implementation in the base class may feel natural or unmotivated. In the latter case you may also look for a different shared place for it, but assuming that the method needs access to protected parts of `Base`, moving it out of `Base` may not be trivial.

Comment: This is definitely a trivial mitigation for the problem as it reduces the length of the duplicate code blocks, but I can't accept that as a solution as I'm trying to get rid of them completely.

Comment: What is code duplication? The same method being called from multiple places in a program doesn’t qualify. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code) duplicate code is *a sequence of source code that occurs more than once*. Note *sequence*.

Comment: I'm analyzing the feasibility of your solution, btw `"I don’t believe in ‘if’ anymore" is the object-oriented battle song` is now one of my favourite quotes

Comment: Well, I'm confused about what to do now. I guess this is a Q&A system limitation. I mean you ARE right, your solution works and answers the question, but it violates the signle responsability principle so badly that it is useless to me, I would never agree to compromise so much the cohesion of the Base class. But this is only because I setted the threshold this hight based on my own personal opinion. (1/2)

Comment: I guess what I really want is an exhaustive discussion on the subject, but I don't think this is the right place to ask for it and I don't even know how to find it. What should I do? Should I give you the correct answer and call it a day? What do you suggest? (2/2)

Comment: It’s an interesting discussion, and I’d still be interested in more background for understanding. You may be right that the Stack Overflow format isn’t perfect for it, though. Setting high goals is useful and inspiring and provokes good thoughts. At the end of the day, design most often ends up in compromises. Another option is you post your own answer stating that there probably is no perfect solution in Java, and then accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: The Base and Derived classes are domain classes while the DoubleDerived classes are  lazy loading Proxies that fetch data from repositories. The fact is that I can pretty much feel that this is a XY problem but I'm so close to the deadline that I know I don't have probably the time to implement the "right" solution.

Comment: In that case your inheritance hierarchy is correct, you should avoid changing it by about all means.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this a candidate for composition over inheritance. If you can enclose the duplicated method in its own class, and invoke it via instances held in the DoubleDerivedX classes, that would eliminate the code duplication. But for that to work, a lot depends on how enmeshed the method is with the rest of the class (which could be an indication there are deeper issues that need addressing).

Comment: I think this solution is simply an isomorphism of the answer of Ole V.V. I guess the problem is in how i stated the question, I will try to improve it by stating the problem more explicitly.